# OtherUserProfile.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') at OtherUserProfile (OtherUserProfile.js:11:1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

OtherUserProfile.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')     at OtherUserProfile (OtherUserProfile.js:11:1)

````
import "./Profile.css"
import { UserContext } from "../App";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function OtherUserProfile() {

    const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState();
    const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);
    const { userId } = useParams();
    // error line
    const [showFollow, setShowFollow] = useState(state ? !state.following.includes(userId) : true);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`/user/${userId}`, {
            method: "get",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                setUserProfile(data);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);``` // we want to lad only once when component is mounting/loading that is why an empty array as dependency
````

Comment: Can you please add the Context also as I need to have a look on your state coming from Context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The basic gist is that `state.following` is undefined.

```
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);

...

const [showFollow, setShowFollow] = useState(state
  ? !state.following.includes(userId)
  : true
);
```

## Solution

You can add a null-check (*Optional-Chaining operator*) to guard against an "accidental" undefined access:

```
const [showFollow, setShowFollow] = useState(state?.following
  ? !state.following.includes(userId)
  : true
);
```

You could ensure that the `UserContext` is providing a `state` object with a defined `following` array.

```
const value = {
  state: {
    ....
    following: /* some array value */ || [], // <-- provided fallback
  },
  dispatch,
};

...

<UserContext.Provider value={value}>
  ...
</UserContext.Provider>
```